# StructureMap CacheBy InstanceScope.HttpSession not working

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap

This is my StructureMap bootstrapping:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(factory =>
{
  //Business Conversation is per session
  factory.ForRequestedType<IConversation>().
    TheDefaultIsConcreteType<Conversation>().
      CacheBy(InstanceScope.HttpSession);

  //Session Factory is life time
  factory.ForRequestedType<INHibernateSessionManager>().
    TheDefaultIsConcreteType<NHibernateSessionManager>().
      CacheBy(InstanceScope.Singleton);
});

var conversation = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IConversation>();
```

When I have my Conversation set to use .CacheBy(InstanceScope.HttpSession), I get Object reference not found, however If I don't use the CacheBy it works fine. This needs to go into the session, I'm not really sure why this isn't working.

Am I doing something wrong or does this appear to be a bug in StructureMap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question, yes this is bug in StructureMap. The bug is fixed in the trunk or will be fixed in any binary release of 2.5.3 or later.